# Configure C++ build task for VScode for MSYS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, msys2

On Windows 11 I have installed VSCode and MSYS64 compiler and debugger.
MSYS bin directory added to path, `gcc --version` command in VSCode terminal return valid string. C++ VScode extension installed and compiler path `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` is set in it.

Still, in VSCode menu *Terminal --> Run Build Task* I do not have *C/C++ g++.exe build active file* option described [in this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from fresh environment by renaming folder `%APPDATA%\Code` solved the problem.